# Do I need a WAF if I have a VPN?

Tags: azure, azure-waf

Do I really need a layer 7 Firewall if I change the architecture to use a VPN? If our clients connect to our services via a VPN, surely that would save costs of a WAF? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A WAF protects your web services and services behind your web.
If you believe in zero trust then people logging into your vpn should not be trusted.
Many believe vpn is a dying tool since it's often configured with poor segmentation.
It's argued that a better alternative to vpn is to use cloud based apps that allow SAML or other methods of authentication/authorization along with 2 factor capabilities.
Hope this helps.